# How to add 2 listeners to map?

Tags: android, dictionary, listener, cluster-computing

i'm developing my first app and i created the following map viewer activity:

```
public class MapViewer extends Activity implements OnInfoWindowClickListener, ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener<MyItem> {

    private GoogleMap map;
    private LatLng defaultLatLng = new LatLng(X, Y);
    private int zoomLevel = 5;
    private Database db = new Database(this);
    private ClusterManager<MyItem> mClusterManager;

    private LatLngBounds allowedBounds;
    private final LatLng northeast = new LatLng(A, B);
    private final LatLng southwest = new LatLng(C, D);

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapviewer);

        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        builder.include(northeast);
        builder.include(southwest);
        allowedBounds = builder.build();

        try {
            map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            if (map != null) {
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                map.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);

                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(defaultLatLng, zoomLevel));

                mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(this, map);
                mClusterManager.setRenderer(new MyClusterRenderer(this, map, mClusterManager));
                mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(this);

                map.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
                map.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

                map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new ClusterInfoWindow(getLayoutInflater())); 
                map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);

                addItems();
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see i set a listener to map object

```
map.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
```

that adds or removes clusters on markers groups, according to zoom level.
Now i would add a listener that checks if user moves on map within some bounds:

```
map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
        checkBounds();
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work. It works only if i remove the previous listener (mClusterManager).
So, how to make both listener working on the same map object?

Thank you in advance for your replies and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there's only a set method and no add method, you can only set one listener at a time. But you could delegate from the one listener to the other like this:

`map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
        checkBounds();
        mClusterManager.onCameraChange(cameraPosition);
    }
});`

Of course mClusterManager does not need to implement the CameraChangeListener interface any more but just needs a method public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition).

Comment: At the moment, your ClusterManager implements the OnCameraChangeListener interface. I don't know the implementation but sth like this: `public class ClusterManager extends SomeOtherClass implements OnCameraChangeListener`. With my approach, you can delete the `implements OnCameraChangeListener`part, as you're not setting that class as a listener any more. But you still keep the method onCameraChange, as you're calling it directly.

Comment: It's not going to cause direct problems, it's more a semantical issue. So, yeah, of course you can keep it if you don't have time or nerve to change it.